# jquery tablesorter not sorting

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, tablesorter

hello
i am stuck with jquery tablesorter:
http://tablesorter.com/docs/index.html#Examples

and would be grateful if some jquery guru could check my code to see where i am going wrong. instead of displaying 10 records per page it is displaying all records and also when i try to sort it does nothing. in addition to that, there are no zebra stripes appearing. all libraies are loaded and there are no errors in firebug. many thanks for your help.

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("sample", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM logger_log WHERE idusr_log = '".$q."' order by datein_log desc";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table id=\"userlog\" class=\"tablesorter\">
<thead>
<tr>
<th align=\"left\">Ip Address</th>
<th align=\"left\">Date In</th>
<th align=\"left\">Date Out</th>
</tr>
</thead>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tbody>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ip_log'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . date('d/m/Y H:i:s',strtotime($row['datein_log'])) . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . date('d/m/Y H:i:s',strtotime($row['dateout_log'])) . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo"</tbody>";
  }
echo "</table>";


mysql_close($con);
?>
<div id="pager" class="pager">
    <form>
        <img src="css/blue/first.png" class="first"/>
        <img src="css/blue/prev.png" class="prev"/>
        <input type="text" class="pagedisplay"/>
        <img src="css/blue/next.png" class="next"/>
        <img src="css/blue/last.png" class="last"/>
        <select class="pagesize">
            <option selected="selected"  value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option  value="40">40</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
<link href="css/blue/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function()     
        {   
            $("#userlog")
            .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})     
            .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});     

        } );
        </script>
```

Comment: Would you mind to show only the client side code? So it is easier to recover your current situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `<tbody>` fom your results loop and place it around your while loop.

```
echo "<tbody>";
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
    echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['ip_log'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . date('d/m/Y H:i:s',strtotime($row['datein_log'])) . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . date('d/m/Y H:i:s',strtotime($row['dateout_log'])) . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";  
  }
  echo"</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: although this was answered correctly a problem has now developed when i incorporate into main php page. do i need to create a new thread to show updated code? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the tbody tags out of the while loop and doing this instead:

```
echo "<table id=\"userlog\" class=\"tablesorter\">
<thead>
<tr>
<th align=\"left\">Ip Address</th>
<th align=\"left\">Date In</th>
<th align=\"left\">Date Out</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>";
```

And then after the while loop:

```
echo "</tbody></table>";
```